# How to validate each form step in material ui stepper?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form

Typical material-ui stepper below.

```
  export default function HorizontalLinearStepper() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
    const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
    const steps = getSteps();

    const isStepOptional = step => {
        return step === 1;
    };

    const isStepSkipped = step => {
        return skipped.has(step);
    };

    const handleNext = () => {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
        newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
        newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }

    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
};

const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep - 1);
};

const handleSkip = () => {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
        // You probably want to guard against something like this,
        // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
        throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(prevSkipped => {
        const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
        newSkipped.add(activeStep);
        return newSkipped;
    });
};

const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
};

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
            {steps.map((label, index) => {
                const stepProps = {};
                const labelProps = {};
                if (isStepOptional(index)) {
                    labelProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
                }
                if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
                    stepProps.completed = false;
                }
                return (
                    <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
                        <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
                    </Step>
                );
            })}
        </Stepper>
        <div>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
                <div>
                    <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                        All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
                    </Typography>
                    <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
                        Reset
                    </Button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</div>
                    <div>
                        <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                            Back
                        </Button>
                        {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={handleSkip}
                                className={classes.button}
                            >
                                Skip
                            </Button>
                        )}

                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={handleNext}
                            type="submit"
                            className={classes.button}
                        >
                            {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Here is function i create to choice step

```
function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return <Step1/>;
        case 1:
            return <Step2/>;
        case 2:
            return 'This is the bit I really care about!';
        default:
            return 'Unknown step';
    }
}
```

Step1 and Step2 are components that has 2 forms inside build with react-final-form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';
import initialValuesCreator from './creationMethods/initialValuesCreator';
import { validationCreator } from './creationMethods/validationSchemaCreator';

class CustomValidationForm extends Component {

    render() {
        const {
            config ,children, submit = () => {}
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <Form
                onSubmit={(event) => {
                    submit(event);
                }}
                initialValues={initialValuesCreator(config)}
                validate={values => validationCreator(values, config)}
                render={({handleSubmit}) => (
                    <form noValidate autoComplete={'off'} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {children}
                    </form>
                )}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

And here comes the question. Material ui stepper has handleNext function. Its my submit for each step. Each step will be some kind of form with validation. When user is on step1 and he press submit i want to show him input errors (something is required etc) and prevent jumping to next step. Step1 can have multiple small forms so all the form should be validated when handleNext is pressed.

Answer (score 6):

I was dealing with it as well
What I finally did to resolve it:

1. Wrapping the pages with a form (instead of the div)
2. Setting a reference to the form using the 'useRef' react hook
3. Check whether or not the form is valid on the 'handleNext' method and return if it's not. The access to the form object is achieved by the useRef hook, and the validity check made by the function 'myForm.current.checkValidity()'

Please give it a shot and let me know if it works for you:

```
export default function HorizontalLinearStepper() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
    const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
    const steps = getSteps();

    const myForm = React.useRef(null);

    const isStepOptional = step => {
        return step === 1;
    };

    const isStepSkipped = step => {
        return skipped.has(step);
    };

    const handleNext = () => {
        if (!myForm.current.checkValidity()) {
           return;
        }
        let newSkipped = skipped;
        if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
            newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
            newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
        }
    
        setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
        setSkipped(newSkipped);
    };
    
    const handleBack = () => {
        setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep - 1);
    };
    
    const handleSkip = () => {
        if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
            // You probably want to guard against something like this,
            // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
            throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
         }
     
        setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
        setSkipped(prevSkipped => {
            const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
            newSkipped.add(activeStep);
            return newSkipped;
        });
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        setActiveStep(0);
    };

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
            {steps.map((label, index) => {
                const stepProps = {};
                const labelProps = {};
                if (isStepOptional(index)) {
                    labelProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
                }
                if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
                    stepProps.completed = false;
                }
                return (
                    <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
                        <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
                    </Step>
                );
            })}
        </Stepper>
        <form action="/" method="POST" ref={myForm}>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
                <div>
                    <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                        All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
                    </Typography>
                    <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
                        Reset
                    </Button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</div>
                    <div>
                        <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                            Back
                        </Button>
                        {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={handleSkip}
                                className={classes.button}
                            >
                                Skip
                            </Button>
                        )}

                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={handleNext}
                            type="submit"
                            className={classes.button}
                        >
                            {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've come up with to do step-wise validation is by breaking the form up into little forms and have a controller component combine all the form values together like in the [Wizard Form Example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/wizard).